# Using a parameter to instantiate a variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, instantiation

I am a beginner programmer, nearing the end of my first semester and my first course in java. In practicing with arrays, I was attempting to implement a method to create an array.

```
public static void genArray1(String arrayID, int cols)
{

    int arrayID[] = new int[cols];
    for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
    {

    }
}
```

I've left the loop empty for the moment as I'm having no trouble with the actual creation of the array/ entering the values, but I am unsure how to create the array with an identifier entered as a parameter. I get

"variable arrayID is already defined in method genArray1(String,int)
        int arrayID[] = new int[cols];"

when i attempt to compile this code.

Comment: ..... Quite self explanitory... Either change the name of your parameter `String arrayID` or change the name of `int arrayID[]`

Comment: parameters passed for the method is consider as local variables for the method and so here you are defining two local variables with same name. thats why compilation error is there.

Comment: Yes, i see where the conflict is, sorry if my question wasn't clear, I am trying to figure out how to use a create a variable/object (in this case an array) with an ID supplied by the user

Comment: @JoeBlake, Why would you want to name a variable using the ID supplied by the user? This would be a case of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you can post your actual problem you are trying to solve, you may get satisfying answers.

Answer (score 0):

You already named a String `arrayID`, so you can't name another variable the same thing. You need to either change the name of the parameter `arrayID` or change the name of your integer array `arrayID`.

Comment: Yes I realize where the conflict is, sorry if i didn't explain my intent/problem clearly. I was trying to create an object with an ID chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is define a variable's name based on a parameter then in Java there is no easy way of doing this, if you would like to do this your best bet would be to look into the Reflection API.

You can learn about reflection here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Though it would be best to explain what you are trying to do as there is no real purpose of doing this for most (if not nearly all) cases.

Comment: My intent was to be able to prompt the user for the name of the variable, I will check out that API but I think it is a bit beyond my scope at this point.


I guess there is really no point to having the user create the actual ID of the array object so I guess I should be making a class the objects of which will contain both an array and a name/ID for that array?